# Is 'also' necessary in "not only... but also..." structures?

Tags: construction, ellipsis

> The car **not only** is economical **but also** feels good to drive.
>
> I identified with Rowan Atkinson **not only** as an actor **but also** as a person.

Yes, both sentences, as they stand, are perfectly acceptable English, but I wonder if one can correctly rewrite them without the word *also*. If not, why not?

Comment: Is removing "BUT" acceptable?

Comment: @mistu, no, it is not.

Comment: What made you think "Not only....But" can be plausible?

Comment: @mistu, I'm unsure, perhaps I have heard this from someone.

Comment: I don't think any close reason would be appropriate here, especially I don't think this question is closeable as  NARQ.

Comment: @Flimzy, thank you. I have edited the question title with the hope it is more clear now.

Comment: @Carlo_R.: I think it's a perfectly good question for ELL (but I'd have probably called GR on ELU). The fact that Mistu4u wonders whether "but" could be omitted, and even StoneyB has misgivings about omitting "also", is surely evidence that there's a degree of uncertainty about this particular "stock" construction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strictly, the idiom requires parallelism. *Not* is paralleled by *but*, and *only* also needs a parallel. It need not be *also*; it may be *too* or *as well* or *in addition*, anything which will complete the contrast with *only*:

> I identified with Rowan Atkinson not only as an actor but as a person, too.

You may very well hear the *also* or equivalent dropped in speech. This is not a *casual* use, but a (venial) mistake which occurs because in speech we often lose track of our syntax.

Comment: Is it really correct to call *not only...but also* an "idiom"? Besides which, although it's a common construction, I don't see why you should imply that *not only* must always be accompanied by something like *also* or *too*. [Here](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22not+only+as+a+man%2C+but+as+a%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) are thousands of instances of *not only as a man, but as a xxxx*, where hardly any of them do this.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  The construction sounds lacking to me. I keep waiting for the *too* to drop ... It's different with *just* or *merely*, but that *only* demands completion. (And it's only 60 uses - but the construction with *also* is only 50, which I suppose would be supplemented with *as well* or *too* constructions. SSS, as my baseball friends say.)

Comment: Weird. "About 14,800 results" turns out to be only 48 when I page through to the end. On the other hand, if I include the word *also*, it starts off by claiming 1,400 results, and that turns out to be only 40 when I try to page through. I think GB is limiting the number of results returned, as well as/rather than just making lousy estimates.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I *never* trust those numbers at the top. You'll notice, too, that whatever your search term, a lot of the hits don't document the use; and on every occasion when I've actually searched the indicated book I found no instance.

Comment: Yeah, but I find it unlikely there really are only those few dozen instances of each of those search terms, in 10's of millions of scanned books. I also suspect that 10:1 ratio in the "guestimates" does reflect a real tendency, though it could be out by a factor of 2 or 3, or even more. I just find GB easier to use than COCA, BNC, etc., for a ***very*** rough guide.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  "Absence of evidence isn't evidence of absence" ... but it's not evidence of anything else, either.

Comment: I believe it's fair to say there are three certainties in this life - *death, taxes*, and the truth of the statement that *absence of evidence proves that either there is no evidence, or we haven't managed to find it yet*. We can still make credible conjectures though - we just have to remember they're always subject to change if and when further information becomes available. And we should actively seek out that additional information - I think Aristotle rather dropped the ball when he didn't even bother to ***count*** the legs on an insect.